# Angular 12 npm run test throws "Couldn't load color-version"

Tags: node.js, angular, unit-testing, npm, karma-jasmine

We recently migrated our application from angular 6 to 12 , everything looks good and i am able to run application(npm start is working) and test the UI features but when i run my angular unit tests(npm run test ) on my local it throwing error and this is only happening on my machine(other peers have no issues with unit test run)

```
    03 03 2022 09:17:14.914:DEBUG [reporter]: Trying to load reporter: @angular-devkit/build-angular--event-reporter
03 03 2022 09:17:14.927:DEBUG [reporter]: Trying to load color-version of reporter: @angular-devkit/build-angular--event-reporter (@angular-devkit/build-angular--event-reporter_color)
03 03 2022 09:17:14.930:DEBUG [reporter]: Couldn't load color-version.
03 03 2022 09:17:14.932:DEBUG [reporter]: Trying to load reporter: @angular-devkit/build-angular--sourcemap-reporter
03 03 2022 09:17:14.933:DEBUG [reporter]: Trying to load color-version of reporter: @angular-devkit/build-angular--sourcemap-reporter (@angular-devkit/build-angular--sourcemap-reporter_color)
03 03 2022 09:17:14.942:DEBUG [reporter]: Couldn't load color-version.
```

I tried re install node/cli/npm install everything.....still no luck

Has anyone seen this error before ? Appreciate your response....

Answer (score 0):

"Couldn't load color-version" is a debug-level message informing you that Karma was unable to find a "colorized" version of the reporter (`@angular-devkit/build-angular--event-reporter_color`).

One reason you might be seeing this message locally and not elsewhere is that you have set your log level to debug (`--log-level debug`).

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**

These messages are only found in the debug logs and can presumably be ignored.

**Gory details**

Within Karma there is a createReporters function found here that is responsible for this output, which is only seen when the logging level is set to debug.

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/master/lib/reporter.js

After loading up each of the reporters, the code then goes on to load the color-version of the reporter with the following code:

```
const colorName = name + '_color'
if (!names.includes(colorName)) {
  try {
    log.debug(`Trying to load color-version of reporter: ${name} (${colorName})`)
    reporters.push(injector.createChild([locals], ['reporter:' + colorName]).get('reporter:' + name))
  } catch (e) {
    log.debug('Couldn\'t load color-version.')
  }
}
```

In the about code, the list of the names of the reporters from the config is iterated over, 'name' refers to the current reporter name being loaded. After loading that reporter, assuming it was found, the code then attempts to load a reporter with that name plus '_color' appended to it (assuming the config does not additionally have the name + '_color' extension listed, making it required). If the reporter without the '_color' name cannot be loaded, an error message is written and an event is emitted stating there was a load error. However, failing to load the '_color' version (extension?) of that loader only results in a debug message being emitted, which is otherwise not present in the logs and does not emit the load error. Presumably, not being able to load the '_color' version does not present any particular issues.

FYI, per the code, the DOTS and PROGRESS reporters seem to have a color extension that is required. As DOTS and PROGRESS are part of Karma, they should be found without needing to load anything else, and indeed the color extensions can be found in the reporters folder near the above referenced code file.